# Using true and false as array index in php?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, logic

I was just working on a sample `web-service` when I came across a specific case, to output result from either of two given values (strings). So, I thought, can I use `true-false` as indexes for array of these strings? To verify, I tested the same and it was working. Logic was clear to me that true and false serve as 1 and 0 indexes of the array:

```
$arr = array(true=>"string1",false=>"string2");
$res = $arr[$test_val];
```

However, I could have achieved the same using:

```
$res = $test_val? "String1":"String2";
```

So, I want to know, which approach is better, as I assume, in either of the approaches, same amount of memory is being used up? Or no, array uses more, right?

Comment: When using Booleans as array keys, they are cast to integers, i.e. the key true will actually be cast to 1 and the key false cast to 0

Comment: I think you are agonising over something not important. But I would go with the ternary just because it is clearer to read. If your app needs this level of optimisation then I am amazed

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, I know that. I clearly pointed out that in question.

Comment: @edmondcommerce: I'm not agonizing. I was just curious. I searched and found no similar question on #stackoverflow. So I just thought to get opinion on this, like a healthy conversation. Not a scoring thing, obviously

Comment: Source of Mark Baker's answer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php: `Bools are cast to integers, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under 1 and the key false under 0.`

Answer (score 3):

Good coding style tends to use the clearest structures, so if your intention is to do a comparison the ternary operators (`?:`) are more appropriate here as they do comparison:

```
$res = $test_val ? 'String1' : 'String2';
```

From a memory / speed point of view: the ternary is probably also faster as it doesn't have to create a memory structure although depending on the size of the application, this is unlikely to have a tangible effect either way.

NB: If you *really* care about optimisation, use single quotes over double quotes where possible as these don't get parsed for variables and special characters :P

Hope this helps :) x

Comment: Suppose we need to deliver the app to a client where he would customise the messages on his end. So, in such a case, wouldn't using arrays (yes, there are still ONLY two values) be the better approach?

Comment: Hmmm... it depends. If you're talking about having a config array elsewhere in the code, which you then reference then yes that'd be a better way of doing it :)

Comment: So I assume this is going to be a tie on 'situation based' approach.. :)

Answer (score 1):

ternary operator will be faster
let's start program run

```
$arr = array(true=>"string1",false=>"string2"); 
$res = $arr[$test_val];
```

what program do :- creating an array assigning two index and values and then array assign to `$arr` then assigned to `$res`

and now ternary

```
$res = $test_val? "String1":"String2";
```

simple `$test_val` will be match with strings and assigned to `$res`
so simply would be faster

Comment: From usability point of view, wouldn't letting the user define those two status messages (consider an end client here) in a different ini file be better? Coz client won't like to hard code strings, right?